# How do I comment out existing database connections & then create a new database connection in the web.config using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, web-config

Basically I have a web.config file that has several database connections in it in both the "connectionStrings" & "appSettings" sections. See example below.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2005 Express -->
    <add
      name="SiteSqlServer"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2000/2005
<add
  name="SiteSqlServer"
  connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> -->
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2005 Express - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules   -->
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;"/>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2000/2005 - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules
<add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;"/>
-->
    <add key="InstallTemplate" value="DotNetNuke.install.config" />
    <add key="AutoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <add key="UseInstallWizard" value="true"/>
    <add key="InstallMemberRole" value="true" />
    <add key="ShowMissingKeys" value="false" />
    <add key="EnableWebFarmSupport" value="false" />
    <add key="EnableCachePersistence" value="false"/>
    <add key="HostHeader" value="" />
    <!-- Host Header to remove from URL so "www.mydomain.com/johndoe/Default.aspx" is treated as "www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx" -->
    <add key="RemoveAngleBrackets" value="false" />
    <!--optionally strip angle brackets on public login and registration screens-->
    <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="0" />
    <!--use as persistent cookie expiration. Value is in minutes, and only active if a non-zero figure-->
    <!-- set UsePortNumber to true to preserve the port number if you're using a port number other than 80 (the standard)
<add key="UsePortNumber" value="true" /> -->
</appSettings>
```

What I need to do is loop through each of the connections strings, comment them out & then add my new connection strings to both sections of the web.config file.

This is what I have so far - creating the new connection string is working but I am unsure how to loop through comment out any orig connection strings.

```
    Dim Name As String = "SiteSqlServer"

    Dim isNew As Boolean = False
    Dim MyWebConfigPath As String = "C:\test\Web.Config"
    Dim MyWebConfigFile As New XmlDocument()

    MyWebConfigFile.Load(MyWebConfigPath)

    Dim list As XmlNodeList = MyWebConfigFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(String.Format("connectionStrings/add[@name='{0}']", Name))
    Dim node As XmlNode

    isNew = list.Count = 0

    If isNew = False Then

        'Comment out existing connection settings

    End If

    node = MyWebConfigFile.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", Nothing)
    Dim attribute As XmlAttribute = MyWebConfigFile.CreateAttribute("name")
    attribute.Value = Name
    node.Attributes.Append(attribute)

    attribute = MyWebConfigFile.CreateAttribute("connectionString")
    attribute.Value = "Data Source=CP5-1234\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=demo_db;User ID=demo_dbusr;Password=MyPass#1234"
    node.Attributes.Append(attribute)

    attribute = MyWebConfigFile.CreateAttribute("providerName")
    attribute.Value = "System.Data.SqlClient"
    node.Attributes.Append(attribute)

    MyWebConfigFile.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("connectionStrings")(0).AppendChild(node)

    MyWebConfigFile.Save(MyWebConfigPath)
```

This is what I would like to end up with:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2005 Express -->
    <!-- REMOVED BY ME ON 6/6/2012
    <add
      name="SiteSqlServer"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> -->
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2000/2005
<add
  name="SiteSqlServer"
  connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> -->
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=CP5-1234\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=demo_db;User ID=demo_dbusr;Password=MyPass#1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2005 Express - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules   -->
    <!-- REMOVED BY ME ON 6/6/2012
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;"/> -->
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2000/2005 - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules
<add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;"/> -->
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=CP5-1234\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=demo_db;User ID=demo_dbusr;Password=MyPass#1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add key="InstallTemplate" value="DotNetNuke.install.config" />
    <add key="AutoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <add key="UseInstallWizard" value="true"/>
    <add key="InstallMemberRole" value="true" />
    <add key="ShowMissingKeys" value="false" />
    <add key="EnableWebFarmSupport" value="false" />
    <add key="EnableCachePersistence" value="false"/>
    <add key="HostHeader" value="" />
    <!-- Host Header to remove from URL so "www.mydomain.com/johndoe/Default.aspx" is treated as "www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx" -->
    <add key="RemoveAngleBrackets" value="false" />
    <!--optionally strip angle brackets on public login and registration screens-->
    <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="0" />
    <!--use as persistent cookie expiration. Value is in minutes, and only active if a non-zero figure-->
    <!-- set UsePortNumber to true to preserve the port number if you're using a port number other than 80 (the standard)
<add key="UsePortNumber" value="true" /> -->
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This seems to be a strange thing to do - can you explain the reasoning behind it? What exactly are you trying to achieve with such a solution?

Comment: Basically i'm creating a windows app to install/upgrade dotnetnuke. Rather than deleting the old connection strings I would prefer just to comment them out so they can easily be reverted back to their original connections if required.

Comment: Have you considered transforming the file using XSLT? It is an XML file after all.